# CSS Layout for Sidebar and Footer DIVs

Tags: css

I have a container that is positioned relatively and contains `div`s for header, sidebar, main-content and footer.

My problem is with the sidebar and footer components. With my sidebar, I have had to position this absolutely with top and left values specified (it also has a z-index of 10 set).

This is all fine, but by having the sidebar as absolute, with the sidebar holding my menu, this sidebar `div` actually sits on top of my footer `div`, which I would like it to sit below the sidebar. So as my menu sidebar grows, my footer `div` (which has no CSS position) just always sits after the height of my menu, which can be any height.

Unfortunately, my site is not hosted as yet and so am unable to point you to it.

Answer (score 0):

Stick to [HTML Layout Gala](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/) and you'll be fine.

Absolute positioning for layout isn't advisable, except in very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

I use `absolute` positioning quite often. You just have to know how to work with it. What you need to do, based off your description, is to set `position: relative` on the footer, then set it's `z-index` higher than your side bar (based off your numbers, at least `11`).